# reset radio button using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="reset">
  <a href="#" ng-click="resetall()">Reset</a>
</div>
<div class="check_box" ng-hide="filter[web.websiteId]" ng-repeat="web in website">                                                  
<label><input type="radio" value="{{web.websiteId}}" id="{{web.websiteId}}" name="webname" ng-click="webcall(web)" ng-model="filter[web.websiteId]" />{{web.websiteName}} ({{web.couponCount}})</label>
```

How i make unchecked the radio button using resetall function .I am using angular js v1.2.17

Comment: you are right, I updated the answer with ng-model, it should be better

Comment: the best would be to add something like web.checked as you already have web.websiteId

Comment: I added a JSFiddle for better explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As ngChecked only works 1 time you can use ng-model:

```
ng-model="testCheck.button1"
```

and in your function resetall:

```
$scope.button1 = false;
```

testCheck should contain x buttons ( button1, 2 ... )

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/aaoub2mg/).

Comment: I try no reset using ng-model but same problem only one it works

Comment: my json file structure: "websites":[{
 "websiteName":"Flipkart",
 "websiteId":"1",
  },
  {
 "websiteName":"asas",
 "websiteId":"5",
  }]

Comment: my controller: $scope.resetall = function () {
        $scope.website.forEach(function (web) {
            web.websiteId = false;
      $scope.onlinedata = $scope.restdata;
        });
    };    its not working properly once i click reset then it reset the radio button but after that when i click on radio button then it pass websiteId false

Comment: I think you should open a new question for the issue with ie 8